# Django urls.py: passing dynamic url parameter into include()

Tags: django, django-urls

I found in Django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-include) that I can pass any constant into `include()` statement. Here in docs' example we are passing `blog_id=3`.

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', include('inner'), {'blog_id': 3}),
]
```

But what if I want to pass dynamic url parameter into `include()`? I mean something like this:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/<int:blog_id>/', include('inner'), {'blog_id': ???}),
]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You omit the `blog_id`. It will simply be included in the kwargs of the included urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do *not* specify the `kwargs`, so you write:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # no { 'blog_id': … }
    path('blog/<int:blog_id>/', include('inner')),
]
```

The url parameter will be passed to the kwargs of the included views.

This is to some extent discussed in the [documentation on *Including other URLconfs*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) where it says:

> (…) For example, consider this URLconf:
>
> ```
> from django.urls import path
> from . import views
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     path('<page_slug>-<page_id>/history/', views.history),
>     path('<page_slug>-<page_id>/edit/', views.edit),
>     path('<page_slug>-<page_id>/discuss/', views.discuss),
>     path('<page_slug>-<page_id>/permissions/', views.permissions),
> ]
> ```
>
> We can improve this by stating the common path prefix only once and
>   grouping the suffixes that differ:
>
> ```
> from django.urls import include, path
> from . import views
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     path('<page_slug>-<page_id>/', include([
>         path('history/', views.history),
>         path('edit/', views.edit),
>         path('discuss/', views.discuss),
>         path('permissions/', views.permissions),
>     ])),
> ]
> ```